# window.location.href does not load URL in ie 8 or ie 9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am having trouble with using window.location.href in ie 8 and ie 9.  When my page loads and the item is clicked the following will not cause the URL to load:

```
window.location.href = "../dashboard";
```

The funny thing is... if I enable developer tools in either ie 8 or ie 9 and close them - doing nothing but open and close the tools window - the URL loads perfectly fine and continues to load fine after that.  This problem does not happen in ie 10 or 11, firefox, chrome, or safari.  I am stumped!  Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe in IE8 you can just use `window.location` not sure about IE9 though.

Comment: Do you have any `console.log()` statements before this? I think those may be stopping it -- they get an error if the console hasn't been opened.

Comment: ^^^ ding ding ding, console logs are errors in old IE when the console is closed, only reason for this behaviour.

Comment: OMG!!! The console.log() was the problem.  Thanks, Thanks, Thanks!

Comment: if you want to keep the console log, you can change it to: if (window.console && window.console.log) { console.log("whatever"); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the console.log() statements in front of the window.location.href and it works great!